# Custom exception message format for Google App Engine - Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, error-handling

I am using Google App Engine with Cloud Endpoints.

By default AppEngines exception format is like this:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "",
    "reason": "",
    "message": "",
    "locationType": "",
    "location": ""
   }
  ],
  "code": <SOME_CODE>,
  "message": ""
 }
}
```

Can I change the format to something else? If yes where should I write the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems if I am using Google Cloud Endpoint, I can't modify the message format.